# How to add spacing in between two custom Table view cells in swift ios?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return leadername.count

}  

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "leadCell") as! LeaderBoardTableViewCell
    cell.leaderNameLbl.text = leadername[indexPath.row]
    cell.areaLbl.text = areaName[indexPath.row]
    cell.approvalLabel.text = approvalrate[indexPath.row]
    cell.leaderImageView?.image = UIImage(named: leaderImage[indexPath.row])
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    //cell.contentView.backgroundColor = transparentColor


            return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 85
}
```

I have checked many solutions but none of them is working for me. i have changed the cell height, tableview height etc. But it's not working for me. How can we achieve this? Please help.

Comment: In my opinion, there are 2 ways for your problem: 1.Each UITableViewCell is display in one section, so you can handle space for each section. 2. In UITableViewCell, set contentView smaller then it shows the space between cells.

Comment: @nynohu How to set the contentview smaller? can you show me in my code how to do it?

Comment: If you use User Interface, you can add all you content into a subview of contentView. And you can control the aize of this subView as you want to display.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by two way.

1) you can add section for each and every cell and add sectionview in section with clear color so that will display blank space between two cell.

2) by designing the tableview cell in a proper way you can make spaces between two cell.

**By the Section footerView :-**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 5 //yourCellArrayCount;
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect (x:0, y: 0, width:10, height: 10))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return view
}
```

if you want to display spacing by UI design then make your view 10px smaller then your cell containerview and set clear color for your cell containerview.

check this image you will get better idea. 
[image]
red color is the main containerview of your cell make it clear color.

**Final output of your table would like this**
[image]

**New Update**

change your tableview methods and place this.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView(frame:CGRect (x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 20) ) as UIView
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return view
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}  

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "leadCell") as! LeaderBoardTableViewCell
cell.leaderNameLbl.text = leadername[indexPath.row]
cell.areaLbl.text = areaName[indexPath.row]
cell.approvalLabel.text = approvalrate[indexPath.row]
cell.leaderImageView?.image = UIImage(named: leaderImage[indexPath.row])
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

//cell.contentView.backgroundColor = transparentColor


        return cell

}
```

check this and change logic for your data display. I have tested this and it will display red space between two cell. once done you can change red to clear color.

Comment: There is no change. It is same as it is. I have changed the contentview background clearcolor.

Comment: first take one cell for example  50 * 50 size now make that cell container view as a clear color and take another view let say it as a tempView with size of (5,5,40,40) and place it in containerView now you need to place all your content  it that tempView and set constraint according to your tempView.  in your heightForCell method return height as a 50. it will work please tell me if you find any problem.

Comment: There is no change

Comment: can you please post your code or cell design so i can help you.

Comment: you don't need to provide height for row so remove that and can you post your cell design and your actual output of table  ?

Comment: i can't understand that code please take a screen shot of your custom cell and post it. also post tableview screenshot when you run  your app in device or simulator.

Comment: I am not able send the screenshot. Is there any other way to sned it?

Comment: do one thing make your tableview background color clear color, and cell separator style none. change your cell's containerview color as Red and subview's color green then run your app and check what you see. also make little bit more space between cell's containerview and subview for testing make space upto 10 to 20 pixel from top bottom leading and tailing so we can check whats wrong with this. also make height for cell 85 to 100. check this https://postimg.org/image/rn0e0m947/.

Comment: also change your cell's backgraound color to clear color

Comment: post image of last two functionality implimentation. so i can check it.

Comment: Can you edit the code which I have send through pastie? So it would be easy for me.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your tableview code but the problem is in your Cell UI design. ok i will try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

A not-so-official way to do this can be adding a little blank empty UIView at the bottom of the UITableViewCell.

Adding this following code in init() of Custom Table View cell may help:

```
var blankView = UIView() 
view.backgroundColor = .clear 
addSubview(blankView)
blankView..translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
blankView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor).isActive = true 
blankView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
```